# A swiftier way to convert String to UnsafePointer<xmlChar> in Swift 3 (libxml2)

Tags: swift, swift3, libxml2, unsafe-pointers

I'm working on a Swift 3 wrapper for the [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org) C-library.

There are two convenience methods to convert `String` to `UnsafePointer<xmlChar>` and vice versa. In libxml2 `xmlChar` is declared as `unsigned char`.

- `UnsafePointer<xmlChar>` to `String` is uncomplicated

  ```
  func stringFrom(xmlchar: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>) -> String {
      let string = xmlchar.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
          return String(validatingUTF8: $0)
      }
      return string ?? ""
  }
  ```
- For `String` to `UnsafePointer<xmlChar>` I tried many things for example

  ```
  let bytes = string.utf8CString.map{ xmlChar($0) }
  return UnsafePointer<xmlChar>(bytes)
  ```

  but this doesn't work, the only working solution I figured out is

  ```
  func xmlCharFrom(string: String) -> UnsafePointer<xmlChar> {
      let pointer = (string as NSString).utf8String
      return unsafeBitCast(pointer, to: UnsafePointer<xmlChar>.self)
  }
  ```

Is there a better, *swiftier* way without the bridge cast to `NSString` and `unsafeBitCast`?

Comment: Your `stringFrom(xmlchar:)` method isn't correctly implemented, the `capacity:` should be the length of the buffer you're receiving, not necessarily 1. I would do `String.decodeCString(xmlchar, as: UTF8.self, repairingInvalidCodeUnits: false)?.result ?? ""` instead. Neither of your implementations for `xmlCharFrom` are correct either; you're attempting to escape pointers that you don't control the lifetime of, in both cases you'll get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swiftiest way I can think of is to just use the `bitPattern:` initializer:

`let xmlstr = str.utf8CString.map { xmlChar(bitPattern: $0) }`

This will give you an `Array` of `xmlChar`s. Hang onto that, and use `Array`'s `withUnsafeBufferPointer` method when you need to pass an `UnsafePointer` to something:

`xmlstr.withUnsafeBufferPointer { someAPIThatWantsAPointer($0.baseAddress!) }`

Don't let the `UnsafePointer` escape from the closure, as it won't be valid outside it.

EDIT: How's this for a compromise? Instead of having your function return a pointer, have it take a closure.

```
func withXmlString<T>(from string: String, handler: (UnsafePointer<xmlChar>) throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
    let xmlstr = string.utf8CString.map { xmlChar(bitPattern: $0) }

    return try xmlstr.withUnsafeBufferPointer { try handler($0.baseAddress!) }
}
```

Or, as an extension on `String`:

```
extension String {
    func withXmlString<T>(handler: (UnsafePointer<xmlChar>) throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        let xmlstr = self.utf8CString.map { xmlChar(bitPattern: $0) }

        return try xmlstr.withUnsafeBufferPointer { try handler($0.baseAddress!) }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, too, but I need to return the pointer from the method.

Comment: @vadian You'll need to do manual memory management then – do you know when the pointers need to be deallocated?

Comment: You should rethink whether you actually need to do that. There's basically not any way to do that that could be considered "Swifty" in any shape or form. With that said, if you really, really have to return a pointer, the only safe way to do it that I can think of is to allocate a new `UnsafeMutablePointer`, copy the bytes to it, and return that. You'll then be responsible for eventually deallocating the memory referred to by the pointer.

Comment: Edited the answer with a possible compromise.

Comment: In Swift 4 you can also say: `func withXmlString(from string: String, handler: (UnsafePointer<xmlChar>) -> ()) { string.withCString(encodedAs: UTF8.self, handler) }`.

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks, but – apologies for my ignorance – how do I apply the closure for a method like `childWith(attributeName: xmlCharFrom(string: attributeName), contains: xmlCharFrom(string: value))`?

Comment: `let child = withXmlString(from: attr) { xmlAttr in withXmlString(from: value) { xmlValue in childWith(attributeName: xmlAttr, contains: xmlValue) } }`

Comment: Alternatively, you could define the `withXmlString` method in an extension on `String`, and get rid of the `from:` attribute. In retrospect this might be a little "Swiftier" than the function as I wrote it. Then it would be: `let child = attr.withXmlString { xmlAttr in value.withXmlString { xmlValue in childWith(attributeName: xmlAttr, contains: xmlValue) } }`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out. I didn't expect that the *swiftier* way is more complicated than the `NSString` / `unsafeBitCast` way.

Comment: It may be more complicated, but it's also more *correct*. The `NSString` / `unsafeBitCast` way gives you a dangling pointer, which becomes invalid as soon as the function exits and the `NSString` you made falls out of scope (the `NSString` *might* be autoreleased, causing it to last until the next time the pool is drained, but this is not documented and thus is not something you can rely on), meaning that any further use of that pointer is undefined behavior. The Swifty way is *safe* and will always work.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: Last question: Your suggestion `let child = withXmlString(from: attr)...` cannot work because the function has no return value. But I need to return the result of my method. How can I do that?

Comment: Whoops, that was an oversight on my part. What you want to do is to make the method generic, and return the generic parameter. Putting `throws` on the closure and `rethrows` on the method will allow you to throw errors as well. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm working on a Swift 3 wrapper for the libxml2 C-library.

Condolences.

> [...] String to UnsafePointer [is complicated]

Agree. It is complicated because it is unclear who owns the xmlChar array.

> [...] the only working solution I figured out is
>
> `let pointer = (string as NSString).utf8String`

This works because of the ownership semantics of `-[NSString utf8String]`:

Apple docs:

> This C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will certainly not have a longer lifetime.

So the lifetime is probably something like the current autorelease pool or even shorter, depending on the compiler's ARC optimisations and the implementation of `utf8String`. Definitely not safe to keep around.

> Is there a better, swiftier way [...]?

Well, that depends on the use case. There's no way to handle this without thinking about the ownership of the created xmlChar buffer.

It should be clear from the API how the functions are using the passed string (even though I know that libxml2's documentation is terrible).

For situations where a string is just used during a function call it might be nice to have a scoped access function:

```
extension String {
    func withXmlChar(block: (UnsafePointer<xmlChar>) -> ()) { ... }
}
```

If the function keeps the pointer around you must guarantee for the lifetime of the pointee. Probably something like a container object that keeps a `Data` and pointer around for some ARC maintained lifetime...

It might be worthwile to go through [one of Mike Ash's recent articles](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-08-11-swiftunmanaged.html) which is about managing ownership of objects beyond ARC.

Comment: Thanks for the condolences, it's not that sad. I got most of the implementation (including XPath support). Actually it's an ObjC project which I'm going to port to Swift.

Answer (score 2):

`String` has a

```
public init(cString: UnsafePointer<UInt8>)
```

initializer, therefore the conversion from an XML string to a Swift string can be simplified to

```
let xmlString: UnsafePointer<xmlChar> = ...
let s = String(cString: xmlString)
```

Ill-formed UTF-8 sequences are replaced by the Unicode replacement
character `U+FFFD`.

---

For the conversion from a Swift string to an XML string I would suggest
a [similar approach as Charles Srstka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965902/1187415), but using the
existing `String.withCString` method instead of creating an intermediate
array:

```
extension String {
    func withXmlString<T>(handler: (UnsafePointer<xmlChar>) throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        return try self.withCString { try handler(UnsafeRawPointer($0).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)) }
    }
}
```

If the throwing option is not needed, it simplifies to

```
extension String {
    func withXmlString<T>(handler: (UnsafePointer<xmlChar>) -> T) -> T {
        return self.withCString { handler(UnsafeRawPointer($0).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)) }
    }
}
```