# Accessing to C object properties from Swift 4

Tags: ios, c, swift, xml, libxml2

I imported the libxml2 C library into a pure Swift project successfully but now I'm facing a new problem. I want to access to the properties of an xmlNode C Type, which is declared like this at the libxml library

```
struct _xmlNode {
    void           *_private;   /* application data */
    xmlElementType   type;  /* type number, must be second ! */
    const xmlChar   *name;      /* the name of the node, or the entity */
    struct _xmlNode *children;  /* parent->childs link */
    struct _xmlNode *last;  /* last child link */
    struct _xmlNode *parent;    /* child->parent link */
    struct _xmlNode *next;  /* next sibling link  */
    struct _xmlNode *prev;  /* previous sibling link  */
    struct _xmlDoc  *doc;   /* the containing document */

    /* End of common part */
    xmlNs           *ns;        /* pointer to the associated namespace */
    xmlChar         *content;   /* the content */
    struct _xmlAttr *properties;/* properties list */
    xmlNs           *nsDef;     /* namespace definitions on this node */
    void            *psvi;  /* for type/PSVI informations */
    unsigned short   line;  /* line number */
    unsigned short   extra; /* extra data for XPath/XSLT */
};
```

For example, I want to access to the `name` property of a xmlNode object named `node`. I know that, using objective-C, that can be done like this `node->name`, but that is not allowed on Swift.

I found the move() function inside the object so I can do `node.move().name` but I'm not sure if that is the way to go.

Also, how can I cast the C types to Swift types easily?

Anyone can point me to the right way?
Thanks.

Comment: This might be helpful: [A swiftier way to convert String to UnsafePointer<xmlChar> in Swift 3 (libxml2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965523/a-swiftier-way-to-convert-string-to-unsafepointerxmlchar-in-swift-3-libxml2).

Comment: @WedgeSparda: Look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html). If I am understanding correctly, then Swift is interoperable with C like with Objective-C. Have you tried importing C header file in your project's Bridging-Header.h?